# package does not exist (Maven)

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, testes

Vamos contextualizar o problema:

Tenho um projeto que consome alguns Web Services, nesse projeto tenho source folders separados conforme padrão sugerido pelo Maven ex:(main/java test/java), as classes geradas com base nos WSDL dos Web Services acabei separando em main/wsdl para que fosse possível excluí-las da cobertura de testes (Eclemma), foi a única forma que eu encontrei para fazer isso.

Quando eu executo o comando install do Maven via Eclipse tudo ocorre bem, porém ao executar o mesmo comando via linha de comando ele lança uma exceção dizendo que os pacotes que constam minhas classes geradas não existem (se perdeu).

Alguém já passou por isso e sabe como resolver?

Comment: Difícil dizer, mas parece que você tem o projeto Eclipse configurado para gerar as classes enquanto o projeto Maven não faz isso. É aquele momento em que você descobre que a IDE maravilhosa que faz tudo pra você acaba atrapalhando quando você tenta fazer as coisas sem ela.

Comment: Se quiser uma resposta mais específica, por favor, edite sua pergunta e acrescente detalhes sobre a geração de classes e sobre a configuração do seu projeto.

Comment: @utluiz não sei quais detalhes eu poderia acrescentar para que fique mais claro, qual parte você não entendeu?

Comment: Poderia postar, por exemplo, o trecho do `pom.xml` onde está configurada a geração de classes a partir do WSDL e também o trecho onde você inclui esse diretório no build. Entenda que o Maven não executa igual pelo Eclipse e por linha de comando. No Eclipse, ele depende de um plugin paga funcionar, que geralmente é o M2E (Maven to Eclipse). Esse plugin faz algumas "mágicas" beseado nas configurações do Eclipse que ficam no arquivo '.project', que ajudam no uso da IDE, mas te deixam na mão sem ela.

Comment: Não é que eu não entendi seu problema, só que não dá para adivinhar a causa sem saber como o projeto está configurado.

Comment: vou tentar esclarecer, os meu pacotes estão separados em: src/main/java (classes criadas por mim), src/main/resources (.properties e etc...) src/main/wsdl (classe geradas com base nos Web Service que consumo de outra aplicação) src/test/java (Testes unitários), quando dou o install pelo eclipse tudo ocorre bem, via linha de comando ele diz que não foi possível encontrar os pacotes (imports) das minhas classe geradas com base nos WSDL

Comment: Eu entendi perfeitamente o que você disse que fez, mas se você não mostra **como** fez não adianta nada. Não tenho como adivinhar. Como vou saber que a configuração feita está correta? Tudo o que eu tenho é a sua palavra de que *deveria* ser de tal e tal jeito. Mas se você acha que sua configuração está correta, então não sou eu quem vou falar que tem alguma coisa faltando ou incorreta.

Comment: @utluiz Acabei resolvendo o meu problema da seguinte forma, movi meu source folder de: src/main/wsdl para src/main/java/wsdl, eu pesquisei um pouco e descobri que o maven por padrão busca os fontes em src/main/java, o que estiver fora disso ele ignora, não achei uma maneira de configurar para que ele achasse em src/main/wsdl, mas como isso resolveu o meu problema por enquanto parei de pesquisar, de qualquer forma agradeço sua contribuição :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adicionei as seguintes configurações no meu pom.xml.

```
 <project>
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
        <artifactId>build-helper-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.1</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>add-source</id>
            <phase>generate-sources</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>add-source</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <sources>
                <source>src/main/wsdl</source>
              </sources>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

Answer (score 0):

A forma que eu resolvi o meu problema foi mover o meu source folder de:

```
src/main/wsdl
```

para:

```
src/main/java/wsdl
```

por algum motivo o Maven busca por padrão os fontes em (src/main/java), o que estiver fora disso ele acaba ignorando, não encontrei uma maneira de configurar para que ele considere o que estiver fora desse padrão.

Comment: O motivo dele buscar nessa pasta é porque é exatamente assim que ele foi projetado, mas é possível adicionar outros diretórios adicionando algumas pequenas coisas figurações no seu POM. Veja, por exemplo: http://blog.sonatype.com/2008/05/adding-additional-source-folders-to-your-maven-build/#.Vmn_Kcs7bqA

Comment: @utluiz eu tentei fazer essas configurações porém não obtive sucesso, devo ter feito algo errado, vou tentar novamente e posto aqui se conseguir

Comment: @utluiz deu certo :)